# Regular Expression Spotfire flavor counting occurrences backwards

Tags: regex, spotfire

I have input strings with arbitrary number of '-' in them and I need a regular expression to return everything from the start of input to the SECOND FROM THE LAST occurrence of '-' or copy of input if there are less than 2 occurrences

```
For example: 

            input: "VS-TEST1-tbl0-max" output: "VS-TEST1"
            input: "VSTEST1-tbl0-max"  output: "VSTEST1"
            input: "AllOneWord"        output: "AllOneWord"
            input: "AllOneWord-VS"     output: "AllOneWord-VS"
```

RegEx language syntax? TIBCO SpotFire one: https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-43748

Much thanks to all regexperts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transform you desire is equivalent to replacing the last 2 blocks (including the separator) with a blank string. The regex to match **only** two end blocks including separator is `(-[^-]*){2}$`

Use [the function `RXReplace`](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/latest/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire_bauthor-consumer_usersguide/bauthcons/topics/en-US/text_functions.html) for this purpose.

Usage example:

```
RXReplace('VS-TEST1-tbl0-max', '(-[^-]*){2}$', '') -> 'VS-TEST1'
```

Comment: What kind of benefit is there in closing a perfectly reasonable question WITH an excellent answer that has been accepted as an answer? Why would you hide a useful solution from anyone looking for it in the future not to mention throw away the effort of 2 people. As for the stated reason - "needs details or clarity", since Haleemur Ali was able to understand it fully from reading the description and to then answer it, it's safe to say the reason is invalid.